# Error with Ansible URI module and variables

Tags: ansible

I have the following code -

```
- name: Create a repo
  uri:
    url: http://mystash.com/stash/rest/api/1.0/projects/PROJECT/repos/
    method: POST
    body: '{"name":"{{ somevar }}_settings"}'
    force_basic_auth: yes 
    status_code: 201 
    headers:
      Content-Type: "application/json"
      Authorization: "Basic bm90bXlwYXNzd29yZA==="
      Accept: "application/json"
```

The issue that I am having is when I try to run this, I get this error -

```
 An unknown error occurred: sendall() argument 1 must be string or buffer, not dict"
```

Is there a way to set the variable that I am passing to it as a string inside of the ansible plan?  Using an = instead of : when passing the value in isn't fixing the issue.

Comment: add a null value to your to your JSON, so that Ansible won't wrongly turn the JSON back into a dict try this http://johndstein-blog.logdown.com/posts/277489-ansible-uri-body-bug

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a JSON based API, then since ansible 2.0 you can use `body_format: json` parameter on the uri module, and actually supply the body in YAML format, and let ansible convert it to JSON.

Doing this is not only nicer, but you are less prone to substitution issues:

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    somevar: data
  tasks:
    - name: Create a repo
      uri:
        url: http://mystash.com/stash/rest/api/1.0/projects/PROJECT/repos/
        method: POST
        body_format: json
        body:
          name: "{{ somevar }}_settings"
        force_basic_auth: yes
        status_code: 201
        headers:
          Content-Type: "application/json"
          Authorization: "Basic bm90bXlwYXNzd29yZA==="
          Accept: "application/json"
```

This will for example send

```
{"name":"data_settings"}
```

as the body